# My TextView in Android doesn't update

Tags: java, android

Although I've checked the solutions for the related questions in this website, I couldn't solve my problem.  I'm trying to build a quiz app that takes the correct answer, adds 1 to the score and updates the score on the score TextView.  I tried calling the score method through android:onClick and also tried the setOnClickListener methods but none of them seem to work.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to the Canada Quiz"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1.  What is the capital of Canada?"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/tokyo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tokyo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/newYork"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New York"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/ottawa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ottawa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/hongKong"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hong Kong"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="calculateScore"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

    </RadioGroup>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scoreButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Calculate score"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And this is my Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ottawa);
        Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scoreButton);
        final TextView scoreShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);

        final boolean rbChecked = rb.isChecked();

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick (View v){
                if(rbChecked){
                    score += 1;
                    scoreShow.setText("Your score is: " + score + "/10");
                }
            }
        });
    }

//    public void calculateScore(){
//        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ottawa);
//        //Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scoreButton);
//        TextView scoreShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreText);
//
//        boolean rbChecked = rb.isChecked();
//        if(rbChecked){
//            score += 1;
//            scoreShow.setText("Your score is: " + score + "/10");
//        }
//    }
}
```

Honestly, it really looks like it would work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only storing the value of the checked state when the view is loaded and it never is updated.

Always check `rb.isChecked()` inside the click listener instead of storing the boolean value outside of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That worked.  But now my scoreShow TextView increments each time I press the calculate button.  Do you know how to come across that?  I want my TextView to increment each time a correct answer is picked because I'm going to add more questions.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
if(rbChecked.isChecked()){
      score += 1;
      scoreShow.setText("Your score is: " + score + "/10");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check for the state of radiobutton when user click on calculate button....your code should be like this...

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick (View v){
            rbChecked = rb.isChecked();
            if(rbChecked){
                score += 1;
                scoreShow.setText("Your score is: " + score + "/10");
            }
        }
    });
```